# Use command inside a VSCode configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code

As per the documentation given [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables), I wish to add a text prompt box when I start my debug configuration. My launch.json file is as follows -

```
{ "version": "2.0.0",
   "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Docker Attach my container",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
        "pipeTransport": {
            "pipeProgram": "docker",
            "pipeArgs": [ "exec", "-i", "${input:containerName}" ],
            "debuggerPath": "/vsdbg/vsdbg",
            "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "quoteArgs": false
        }
    }
   ],
   "inputs": [
       {
            "id": "containerName",
            "type": "promptString",
            "description": "Please enter container name",
            "default": "my-container"
       }
   ]
}
```

However with this VSCode does not give the prompt for me to enter container name. Any ideas why this would be the case?

Also further question, ideally I wish to execute a shell script that can run docker ps + some `grep` to filter out the correct container name automatically. So if that can be done and then passed to this configuration as an argument, that would be even ideal.

Comment: if you replace `${input:containerName}` with a valid container name does it work? If so you can file an issue to allow variable substitution in the `pipeArgs` strings

Answer (score 1):

For the second part you can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) to use the content of a file as a variable of via a Key-Value pair.

Write a shell script that does your `docker ps` and `grep` that produces the result in a file in a `preLaunchTask`.

Use the command `extension.commandvariable.file.content` in an `${input:xxxx}` variable and use the extension to read the content of the file to be used in the launch command.